# ReduxForm and ReactRouter - Form Not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-router-dom

I'm refactoring some code on my first react app, which is a simple login form that redirects and renders a list of items on successful login. I have a form container, connected to the redux store, that should render a login form - decorated with reduxForm. I don't understand why the form is not rendering.

***index.jsx***

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

***App.jsx***

```
import {LoginFormContainer} from './components/Login/LoginFormContainer'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={LoginFormContainer}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

***LoginFormContainer.jsx***

```
import LoginFormComponent from './LoginFormComponent';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form/immutable';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

let LoginFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form: 'login',
})(LoginFormComponent)

const mapStateToProps = null
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSubmit: loginFormValues => {
      dispatch(loginUser(loginFormValues))
    }
    }
}

const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) =>
    Object.assign({}, stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps)

LoginFormContainer = withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(LoginFormContainer))

export default LoginFormContainer
```

***LoginFormComponent.jsx***

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <Col xs={12} md={12}>
          <form>
            <FormGroup>
              <Field
                name="username"
                type="email"
                component={renderField}
                label="Username"
                validate={[required]}
              />
            </FormGroup>
            <FormGroup>
              <Field
                name="password"
                type="password"
                component={renderField}
                label="Password"
                validate={[required]} />
            </FormGroup>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
    }
}

export default LoginForm
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply removing the curly braces from the import of LoginFormContainer in App.jsx fixed the issue. `import LoginFormContainer from './components/Login/LoginFormContainer'`

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minor exports/imports missing.

**LoginFormContainer.jsx**

```
import LoginFormComponent from './login_form_component';
import {reduxForm} from 'redux-form/immutable';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import { connect } from 'react-redux'; // missing import

// need to export these variables to be used below

export const LoginFormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: 'login',
})(LoginFormComponent)

export const mapStateToProps = null
export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onSubmit: loginFormValues => {
      dispatch(loginUser(loginFormValues))
    }
  }
}

// this is not needed 
// export const mergeProps = (stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps) =>
//     Object.assign({}, stateProps, dispatchProps, ownProps)

// withRouter is not needed unless you need any of the 
// functionality here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginFormContainer)
```

**LoginFormComponent.jsx**

Not sure if you just did not include the imports for this file. Make sure to have this in there 
`import React, { Component }  from 'react';`

Comment: I left the imports out for the sake of brevity. There are no errors, the form just doesn't render.